# Is prosecutorial discretion subject to the public sector equality duty?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, discrimination, prosecutorial-discretion, equality-act-2010

The Equality Act 2010 creates a duty on public sector entities to have consideration for equality in all decisions they take. Does this bear on prosecutorial offices and their exercises of prosecutorial discretion?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, decisions must not be contrary to [section 149](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/149?timeline=false) Equality Act 2010, which defines "Public sector equality duty" to mean:

> (1)A public authority must, in the exercise of its functions, have due regard to the need to—
>
> - (a)eliminate discrimination, harassment, victimisation and any other conduct that is prohibited by or under this Act;
> - (b)advance equality of opportunity between persons who share a relevant protected characteristic and persons who do not share it;
> - (c)foster good relations between persons who share a relevant protected characteristic and persons who do not share it.
>
> ...
>
> (7)The relevant protected characteristics are—
>
> - age;
> - disability;
> - gender reassignment;
> - pregnancy and maternity;
> - race;
> - religion or belief;
> - sex;
> - sexual orientation.
>
> (8)A reference to conduct that is prohibited by or under this Act includes a reference to—
>
> - (a)a breach of an equality clause or rule;
> - (b)a breach of a non-discrimination rule.
>
> (9)Schedule 18 (exceptions) has effect.

**And** as long at the Crown prosecutor exercises discretion by deciding to / not to, for example [charge a suspect](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/94557/35069) based on a subjective reading of the evidence etc, and **not** one of the above protected characteristics, then the prosecutor has complied with the equality duty.

Comment: When does the prosecution service perform a judicial function?

Comment: @Seekinganswers It was only intended as a footnote to supplement s.149's reference to Sch 18. With hindsight, para 3(2) is more appropriate but off the top of my head I can't readily find a usable example, so I've taken it out until (or if) I can.

Comment: Okay but the question still stands. Perhaps it is worth its own question but I really just intended it as a commentary one.